# Thymeleaf-Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have created a web application with Thymeleaf + Spring Boot.
It was working fine for the last few days. I tried to convert to war file, instead of JAR to deploy in Apache Tomcat Server.

As it was not working, I reverted the changes. After that, its behaviour is unpredictable. Now it is not detecting webjar and bootstrap jar which is added in the classpath, so none of the layout is coming correct.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: just check under the problems section if you're using eclipse

Comment: The system is not able to identify any of the images in the image folder or files in css.."/" is getting replaced automatically,

Comment: Error is attached below:

Comment: IN this case, img.png is the image in images folder..but it is automatically replacing "/" 
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "imagesimg.png", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "fragments/layout" - line 58, col 11)
 at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:870) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
 at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseStandalone(TemplateManager.java:250) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
 at

Comment: Thank you. I resolved the issue. In my controller, I have written to replace / with empty spaces. I had created a common controller, which was getting called for all views, that was creating the issue.